# the_field doesn't work after put one custom post type into another custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

i have such code:

```
                <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'tariffs',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'type_of_site' => 'landing_page_type_hr',

                );

                $webTariffs = new WP_Query($args);

                while ($webTariffs->have_posts()) :
                    $webTariffs->the_post();

                ?>
                    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                    <span class="website-price"><?php the_field('Tariff price euro'); ?>
                        <?php the_content() ?>

                <?php       
                    endwhile;
                ?>
```

this code display custom post type on page like this:
[image]

When i create a new custom post type not as an element but as page and display this element on my page is working. Also before this code `<?php the_field('name_of_page_field') ?>` is working. But...

The problem: If i try to use `<?php the_field('name_of_field') ?>` after this code i have no results.

Maybe i can somehow clear all arguments or while loop after this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

it was needed in the end of the code